Doubt in the Coriolis component of the net force acting on the aircraft
I dig a little and got to know that the force equation in 6DOF are nothing but a mathematical depiction of the fact that for a translating & Rotating body in 3D,The net force is the Translational force +Coriolis force.
In all the text books Coriolis force is defined as
$-2m(\boldsymbol{\omega} \times \textbf{v} )$.
Where  $\times$ = Vector product, $\boldsymbol{\omega} $=Angular velocity, $\textbf{v}$=Linear velocity
So if I follow this, Coriolis force in x direction should come as $-2m(qw-rv)$.
But in the Fx equation of the 6DOF,the Coriolis term is coming as $m(qw-rv)$, there is $-2$ missing, and off course that is also correct but it's confusing.
Can anyone help me in filling the dots that I'm missing?

I think this question is better suited on https://physics.stackexchange.com/

According to How Airplanes correct for the Coriolis Effect, Coriolis force requires a correction of 0.00021 % of the thrust. But the explanation seems great.
